# XML replace value with Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath, linq-to-xml

The following is my XML:

```
<Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/x/xxxxx.xsd" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
<saml:Assertion ID="xxxxx" IssueInstant="xxxxxxx" Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
<saml:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:unspecified">MyApp</saml:Issuer>
<saml:Subject>
  <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:unspecified">MyApp</saml:NameID>
</saml:Subject>
<saml:AttributeStatement>
  <saml:Attribute Name="UserID" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
    <saml:AttributeValue>TestUserID</saml:AttributeValue>
  </saml:Attribute>
  <saml:Attribute Name="UserFirstName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
    <saml:AttributeValue>TestUserFirstName</saml:AttributeValue>
  </saml:Attribute>
  <saml:Attribute Name="UserLastName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
    <saml:AttributeValue>TestUserLastName</saml:AttributeValue>
  </saml:Attribute>
  <saml:Attribute Name="ReasonForSearch" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
    <saml:AttributeValue>ReasonForSearch</saml:AttributeValue>
  </saml:Attribute>
</saml:AttributeStatement>
</saml:Assertion>
</Security>
```

In my code I want to replace TestUserLastName, TestUserFirstName, TestUserID and ReasonForSearch with proper values.

I tried doing something like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("C:/TFS/xxx/yyy/zzz/SAMLAssert.xml");

        XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("sa", "saml:Assertion");
        xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("sas", "saml:AttributeStatement");
        xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("satt", "saml:Attribute");
        xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("sattv", "saml:AttributeValue");

        XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("/sa/sas/satt");
```

But `xnList` count is always 0.  I would love to do this in Linq-to-XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would love to do this in Linq-to-XML.

Here you are:

```
// load document
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("Input.txt");
// prepare XNamespace instance
var saml = XNamespace.Get("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");

// query for items and put them into Dictionary<string, XElement>
var attributes = xDoc.Root.Element(saml + "Assertion")
                          .Element(saml + "AttributeStatement")
                          .Elements(saml + "Attribute")
                          .ToDictionary(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name"), x => x.Element(saml + "AttributeValue"));

// update XElement values using created Dictionary
attributes["UserID"].Value = "New UserID";
attributes["UserFirstName"].Value = "New UserName";
attributes["UserLastName"].Value = "New UserLastName";
attributes["ReasonForSearch"].Value = "New ReasonForSearch";

// save updated document back
xDoc.Save("Input.txt");
```

Result XML:

```
<Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/x/xxxxx.xsd" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
  <Assertion ID="xxxxx" IssueInstant="xxxxxxx" Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:unspecified">MyApp</Issuer>
    <Subject>
      <NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:unspecified">MyApp</NameID>
    </Subject>
    <AttributeStatement>
      <Attribute Name="UserID" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <AttributeValue>New UserID</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute Name="UserFirstName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <AttributeValue>New UserName</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute Name="UserLastName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <AttributeValue>New UserLastName</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute Name="ReasonForSearch" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <AttributeValue>New ReasonForSearch</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
    </AttributeStatement>
  </Assertion>
</Security>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a question, why did we not use the sequrity tag namespace

Comment: You don't have to use namespace when using `XDocument.Root` property.

Comment: Another behavior i noticed is that after saving the xml that is rendered is that all tag changes from <saml:Assertion .....> to <Assertion ....> wont that potential be an issue. or is it the same thing

Comment: That's the same thing, because starting from `<Assertion>` `saml` namespace is set as default using `xmlns` attribute, so you don't have to repeat it on every element.

Comment: I really appreciate all your help. Bacically I am adding this xml to the Wcf soap header request using OperationContextScope. Since I dont have the indepth knowledge and understanding of WCF. I dint know how the change <saml:Assertion .....> to <Assertion ....> will effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("oasis", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/x/xxxxx.xsd");
xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("saml", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");

XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("/oasis:Security/saml:Assertion/saml:AttributeStatement/saml:Attribute");
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested. I am getting Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.

Comment: I didnt copy your `XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);` line. Did you remove it? BTW, I know nothing about Linq-to-XML, I only looked at the XPath part and namespaces

Comment: Yes i had added XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable); in my code if i dont add that the code will not complie. I know the issue id with attributes we cannot have zbc:xyz when give path of node.